# Create image from NSString properly

Tags: objective-c, uiimage, core-graphics

I am creating a image from string variable. Following is the code snippet to create image

```
-(UIImage *)imageFromText:(NSString *)text FontName:(UIFont *)font
{
    // set the font type and size
    //UIFont *font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:20.0];  
    CGSize size  = [text sizeWithFont:font];

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(size);

    [text drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(0.0, 0.0) withFont:font];

    // transfer image
    CGContextSetShouldAntialias(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), YES);
    CGContextSetAllowsAntialiasing(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), YES);

    UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();    

    return image;
}
```

Above code works well but problem is that final image is blurred.
Please advice if anything is wrong in above code.

Comment: note: above codes deprecated since iOS 7

Answer (score 1):

Use `UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(CGSize size, BOOL opaque, CGFloat scale)` instead of `UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(size`)

Set Scale according to the screen size. This will help you and you will not get any blurred image.