# How to use a glyph icon in place of a UITabBarItem image?

Tags: ios, ios7, uitabbaritem, glyphicons

I am new to iOS development and working on a iOS mobile app where I would like to use a glyph icon instead of the UITabBarItem image. But I am not able to figure out how can I use this. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

you can create image from NSString ([Create image from NSString properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9162838/create-image-from-nsstring-properly)) and add UITabBarItem by code ([How to programmatically add UITabBarItem's Identifier type in iOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10250688/how-to-programmatically-add-uitabbaritems-identifier-type-in-ios))

Comment: I am doing the same thing using this tutorial http://www.blog.montgomerie.net/iphone-images-from-character-glyphs
But it generates a blurred image..

Comment: IMHO using images is faster for you and your app - you don't have to create image every reload UI